# Infinate loop with fetching data in UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Having a weird issue where by i am fetching some data from my local api, and it is infinately calling it for some strange reason:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Users = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

    const fetchUsers = async () => {
        try {
            await fetch('http://localhost:3001/users')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setUsers(data));
        }
        catch(ex) {
            console.error('ex:', ex);
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUsers();
    }, [users])

   return <div>xxx</div>
}

export default Users;
```

If I `console.log(data)` instead of `setUsers(data)`, then all seems to be fine and the console log only outputs 1 set of information.

I am unsure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove `users` as a dependency of `useEffect`. You don't need it, and this causes the infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
}, [users])
```

should be:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
}, [])
```

The first will fetch users every time user changes. then it changes the users object with the results which causes the infinite loop.

The fix instead only calls it once on mount.

Answer (score 1):

Your effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
}, [users]);
```

will be executed whenever someone changes users object. In this case, the first time you will call useEffect, and fetch data from API, when you receive data from the backend you will update users object and trigger an infinite loop.

You can solve problem with:

```
useEffect(() => { fetchUsers(); }, []);
```